# Getting warnings when using the "list" method of Google Drive API using PHP

Tags: php, list, google-drive-realtime-api

We are using the Google Drive API for PHP in our web application, and although listing, inserting and deleting work just fine, we keep getting these warnings when using the `list()` method:

```
$google_return = $GoogleAPI['Drive']->files->list();
```

causes these two warnings to appear:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in (...)lib/php/GOOGLE/service/Google_ServiceResource.php on line 108
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in (...)lib/php/GOOGLE/io/Google_REST.php on line 92
```

I tried modifying the API files themselves and added an `is_array` check before that foreach, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The client API is downloaded from here
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

The below code causes a warning, so I added the `is_array` check but that didn't eliminate it.

```
$method['parameters'] = array_merge($method['parameters'], $this->stackParameters);
if (is_array ($parameters) {
     foreach ($parameters as $key => $val) {
        if ($key != 'postBody' && ! isset($method['parameters'][$key])) {
          throw new Google_Exception("($name) unknown parameter: '$key'");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You should probably add more code to your question. As a starter, provide a URL where you can download that API. And probably show your fix that doesn't work.

Comment: Should you not be iterating `$method['parameters']` rather than `$parameters`?

Comment: Hi. This is code from the google API client, not mine. I'm not even supposed to modify it. The is_array check was added just to try and eliminate the warning. My code is : $google_return = $GoogleAPI['Drive']->files->list();